# Get new name to show in angular scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a simple angular controller to post a new name and display the name on the page.

The problem is I cant see the name and the rest of the details to show in the scope ....

Any idea how to fix this and why its not working ?

**HTML**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Base64 Upload Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload/master/src/angular-base64-upload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="UpLoadImage">

    <div ng-repeat="step in stepsModel">
        <img class="thumb" ng-src="{{step}}"/>
    </div>

    <label for="file">Select File</label>
    <input type='file' name='file' base-sixty-four-input required onload='onLoad' maxsize='600'
           accept='image/*' ng-model-instant onchange='angular.element(this).scope().imageUpload(this)'/>
</div>

<div ng-controller="PostData">
    {{items.c_name}}

    <form ng-submit="sendPost()">
        <input ng-model="newName"/>
        <button type="submit">Send Data</button>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['naif.base64'])
.controller('UpLoadImage', function ($scope, $http, $window, $rootScope) {

    $scope.imageUpload = function (element) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    };

    $scope.imageIsLoaded = function (e) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.stepsModel.push(e.target.result);
        });

        $scope.onLoad = function (e, reader, file, fileList, fileOjects, fileObj) {
            alert('image uploaded');
        };
    };

    $scope.stepsModel = [];
})

.controller('PostData', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items = {
        c_name: "Campaign name here",
        max_slots: 5,
        slots: [
            {
                slot_id: 1,
                base_image: "base 64 image"
            }
        ]
    };

    $scope.newName = "Enter name";
    $scope.sendPost = function() {
        var data = $.param({
            json: JSON.stringify({
                c_name: $scope.newName
            })
        });
        $http.post("/echo/json/", data).success(function(data, status)  {
            $scope.items = data;
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed **ng-model** property in base-sixty-four-input directive input:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['naif.base64'])
.controller('UpLoadImage', function ($scope, $http, $window, $rootScope) {

    $scope.imageUpload = function (element) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    };

    $scope.imageIsLoaded = function (e) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.stepsModel.push(e.target.result);
        });

        $scope.onLoad = function (e, reader, file, fileList, fileOjects, fileObj) {
            alert('image uploaded');
        };
    };

    $scope.stepsModel = [];
})

.controller('PostData', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items = {
        c_name: "Campaign name here",
        max_slots: 5,
        slots: [
            {
                slot_id: 1,
                base_image: "base 64 image"
            }
        ]
    };

    $scope.newName = "Enter name";
    $scope.sendPost = function() {
        var data = $.param({
            json: JSON.stringify({
                c_name: $scope.newName
            })
        });
        $http.post("/echo/json/", data).success(function(data, status)  {
            $scope.items = data;
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Base64 Upload Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload/master/src/angular-base64-upload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="UpLoadImage">

    <div ng-repeat="step in stepsModel">
        <img class="thumb" ng-src="{{step}}"/>
    </div>

    <label for="file">Select File</label>
    <input ng-model="file" type='file' name='file' base-sixty-four-input required onload='onLoad' maxsize='600'
           accept='image/*' ng-model-instant onchange='angular.element(this).scope().imageUpload(this)'/>
</div>

<div ng-controller="PostData">
    {{items.c_name}}

    <form ng-submit="sendPost()">
        <input ng-model="newName"/>
        <button type="submit">Send Data</button>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure property *c_name* exists on the data returned by the *$http.post* ? . Add a console log to print what you really get. You also have to ensure there is no error by setting an error callback. I also suggest to give a name other than *data* for the result (*res* instead of *data* for example):

```
    var data = {}; // There is already a variable named data here
    $http.post("/echo/json/", data).success(function(res, status)  {
        $scope.items = res;
        console.log("$scope.items: ", $scope.items);
    }, function() { console.log("There is an error"); })
```

Answer (score -1):

- Add ng-modal to input where you used base-sixty-four-input directive.
- Add cdn path of jquery.